# Weird overlay display issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax function and thought it would be nice to include a little ajax-spinner to tell the enduser something is actually happening. This is my current jQuery function:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let overlay = $('#overlay'),
        loader = $('#loader-popup');

    console.log(overlay);
    console.log(loader);

    console.log('===================');

    //show overlay
    overlay.removeClass('hidden');
    loader.removeClass('hidden');

    console.log(overlay);
    console.log(loader);

    let formData = new FormData($(this)[0]),
        params = [];

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/pages/contact-us/action/send.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res)
        {
            if (res == 1) {
                params['type'] = 1;
                params['msg'] = 'We will be with you as soon as we can!'
            } else {
                try {
                    res = $.parseJSON(res);
                    let data = [];

                    $.each(res, function(key, value) {data.push(value)});

                    params['type'] = 2;
                    params['msg'] = data.join('<br />')
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    alert('Huh. that\'s weird, something went wrong! Please try again');

                    //cause syntax error to stop script working
                    die()
                }
            }

            validator.displayAlert(params['type'], params['msg'])
        },
        error: function(res)
        {
            console.log(res);
            alert('Don\'t worry.. it\'s not you, it\'s us.')
        }
    });

    //hide overlay
    overlay.addClass('hidden');
    loader.addClass('hidden');
});
```

But weirdly the overlay doesn't show, nor does the loader. What makes this hard to kinda debug and fathom is the `console.log` output.

> **first console.log(overlay)**
>   Object [ div#overlay.hidden ]
>
> **second console.log(loader)**
>   Object [ div#loader-popup.hidden ]
>
> **third console.log(overlay)**
>   Object [ div#overlay ]
>
> **fourth console.log(loader)**
>   Object [ div#loader-popup ]

So I can see that my `.removeClass()` function is working, however, inspecting my page once the form is being submitted shows the elements with the `hidden` class. If I manually remove that `hidden` class in the `inspector` tab then everything shows, so I know it's not a CSS issue.

You can see this happen on a much simpler scale [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hszgd6p0/)

I've also tried with `.toggle()` with no avail.

How do I even begin to debug something that seems to work behind-the-scenes but, not on screen?

Comment: You have the `overlay.addClass('hidden');` line outside the async ajax call? Surely this should be inside else it will be called straight away? Perhaps inside the success callback?

Answer (score 2):

You should call hide the overlay in your callback, because it'll be executing asynchronously.

Something like

```
try {
    res = $.parseJSON(res);
    let data = [];

    $.each(res, function(key, value) {
        data.push(value)
    });

    params['type'] = 2;
    params['msg'] = data.join('<br />')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert('Huh. that\'s weird, something went wrong! Please try again');

    //cause syntax error to stop script working
    die()
} finally {
    //hide overlay


    overlay.addClass('hidden');
    loader.addClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic within the `$.ajax()` call is asynchronous. As such you remove the class then immediately add it back in as the AJAX request is in progress.

To fix this, change the `addClass()` calls to be made *after* the AJAX request completes. In your case the best place to do this would be in the `complete` callback as it will fire whether the AJAX request completed successfully or with an error:

```js
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let $overlays = $('#overlay, #loader-popup').removeClass('hidden');
  let formData = new FormData(this),
    params = [];

  $.ajax({
    // ajax settings...
    complete: function() {
      $overlays.addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ah.. bout to rm question, should be closed as can't be reproduced.. plus probs a dupe out there about async usage that would apply here.. sorry!

Comment: No problem. Also note that you can just use `this` in the FormData call. Right now you're using a Element object to create a jQuery object just to get the Element back out of it again.

Comment: Ah didn't know that! Thought as I was in a jQuery obj, `this` might not equal `$(this)` but that's cool, thank you ^.^